# Come si dice "I was wrong about him" in italiano?

Tags: phrase-request

Questa è una frase che non ho sentito spesso in italiano, e non riesco a   tradurla bene. Oppure quando si dice: "there is misunderstanding": esiste  una frase tradotta direttamente? So che c'è "non ci siamo capiti", ma questo è leggermente diverso.

Comment: ***"Mi sono sbagliato/a su di lui"***  is a  common sentence you may use.

Comment: @Gio grazie mille, non l'avevo sentito

Answer (score 4):

Gio's comment, "Mi sono sbagliato su di lui", is correct.

Other possible forms are

- "Mi ero fatto un'idea sbagliata su di lui"
- "Avevo (avuto) l'impressione sbagliata su di lui"

Comment: Aggiungerei "Mi sono sbagliato sul suo conto"

Answer (score 2):

Esiste anche una variante "mi sbagliavo su di lui". La scelta di questa o quella frase credo sia per lo più regionale.

Riguardo alla tua seconda richiesta, ovvero "there is misunderstanding", in italiano c'è il corrispettivo (letterale) "c'è stato un malinteso".

In teoria la traduzione alla lettera dovrebbe essere "c'è un malinteso", ma sinceramente non credo di aver mai sentito la forma al presente.

Comment: Tutto giusto, ma non mi sembra molto utile aggiungere anche la “traduzione alla lettera”. Se uno ti chiedesse come si dice in italiano “how old are you?”, dopo avergli spiegato “quanti anni hai?” etc. non gli diresti anche “come vecchio sei tu?”, no?

Comment: il problema è che la forma al presente ha perfettamente senso. In inglese anche si dice "there has been a misunderstanding", di conseguenza per il fatto che lui ha usato il presente, ho fatto la precisazione.

Comment: Bene, mi è chiaro il perché della tua spiegazione.